# Visualizing geographic- Information in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, gis, data-visualization, bigdata

I have a selected geographic data set with ST_Bin Ids. Now i want to visualize them in a map. What is the easiest way do this?

(I can downloaded this data set to local machine. But I don't have actual coordinates)

Comment: `ST_Bin` from what framework?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you can view the geographic data in based on you have proper geographical data

**HUE Editor** and **Elasticsearch Geolocation**

http://gethue.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/search-only.png
http://blog.eslimasec.com/2014/05/elastic-security-deploying-logstash.html

**Hope this Helps!!!..**